# Add variables to an array that was already declared in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to be able to have an empty array when the program starts, fill it up during runtime, and also remove things inside of it. This would probably have to be a multidimentional array. So, how would I do this?

Ex.

```
int randomNumber;
int RandomString;
int array[] = {};
for(int i;int i < 10; int i ++){

array + random variable;
array + random string;

}
```

So, after it would look like:

> array[] = {{randomint,randomstring},{randomint, rrandomstring}}

Is this possible?

Comment: `for(int i;int i < 10; int i ++){` You should declare `i` only once, in the initialisation part of the `for` loop header.

Comment: Yes that is not my actual code, I muffed up haha

Comment: Wouldn't compile anyway.

Comment: arrays are fixed size sequences. it's obviously from your description that it's not an array you're looking for, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

You'd do it using a `std::vector` and `push_back()` instead. Nuff' said.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add predefined variable into array there are possibly two things you want to hold, one is the value of the variables and the second is the variable itself

if you want to have the value of the variable that is pretty simple, if you want to have it on array not on some dynamic data type then you have to declare an array of limited size 
for dynamic expansion of array you have to use some type of data structure like vector or linked list and add the value of the variable right there 
but if you want to hold the variable it self then you have to declare the arrays of pointer and store the addresses of the variables, in such way you would be able to access those variables by using that array .

Comment: Suggest adding some pseudo-code to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to think about the container you wish to use wether it be a list a map or a vector, they all have pro's and cons. Do some more homework before making a decision my gut says either a vector or a list of lists Only since you want an empty one and then add to it. Consider wether this Container is going to be ordered and if you will want to enumerate through it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is build a Vector map, which contains a pair.
Then when you loop over your data, you create a new pair and assign the values you need.
 Then push it into the vector.

```
int randomNumber = 0;
string randomString = "test";

map< int, vector <pair< int, string >>> myArray;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    pair<int, string> p;
    p.first = randomNumber;
    p.second = randomString;

    myArray[i].push_back(p);
}
```